# Extract ZIP file, including hidden files

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm using ZipArchive and I want to extract ZIP file.
I can see a comment in the docs for ZipArchive::extractTo:

> Note, in Linux (possibly other *nix platforms too) there is no way to extract hidden files ( aka filename starting with a '.') from a Zip archive.

And very important note: I need it to work on both *nix and Windows platforms.

So how to properly extract ZIP file into dir, including hidden files?

Thanks in advance,
JK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) functions if the server allows them :

```
system("unzip archive.zip");
```

There are although [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Since OP looking for pure-php solution here is a user implemented function for php manual ([Zip Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php#75079)) :

```
<?php
/**
* Unzip the source_file in the destination dir
*
* @param   string      The path to the ZIP-file.
* @param   string      The path where the zipfile should be unpacked, if false the directory of the zip-file is used
* @param   boolean     Indicates if the files will be unpacked in a directory with the name of the zip-file (true) or not (false) (only if the destination directory is set to false!)
* @param   boolean     Overwrite existing files (true) or not (false)
* 
* @return  boolean     Succesful or not
*/
function unzip($src_file, $dest_dir=false, $create_zip_name_dir=true, $overwrite=true)
{
  if ($zip = zip_open($src_file))
  {
    if ($zip)
    {
      $splitter = ($create_zip_name_dir === true) ? "." : "/";
      if ($dest_dir === false) $dest_dir = substr($src_file, 0, strrpos($src_file, $splitter))."/";

      // Create the directories to the destination dir if they don't already exist
      create_dirs($dest_dir);

      // For every file in the zip-packet
      while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
      {
        // Now we're going to create the directories in the destination directories

        // If the file is not in the root dir
        $pos_last_slash = strrpos(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "/");
        if ($pos_last_slash !== false)
        {
          // Create the directory where the zip-entry should be saved (with a "/" at the end)
          create_dirs($dest_dir.substr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), 0, $pos_last_slash+1));
        }

        // Open the entry
        if (zip_entry_open($zip,$zip_entry,"r"))
        {

          // The name of the file to save on the disk
          $file_name = $dest_dir.zip_entry_name($zip_entry);

          // Check if the files should be overwritten or not
          if ($overwrite === true || $overwrite === false && !is_file($file_name))
          {
            // Get the content of the zip entry
            $fstream = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            file_put_contents($file_name, $fstream );
            // Set the rights
            chmod($file_name, 0777);
            echo "save: ".$file_name."<br />";
          }

          // Close the entry
          zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }      
      }
      // Close the zip-file
      zip_close($zip);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, but I'm looking for pure-PHP solution if possible. And very important note: I need it to work on both *nix and Windows platforms.

Comment: Ok, take a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php there are some user's implemented functions that could help you.

Comment: That said, `shell_exec()` should work on both (unix and windows) systems.

Comment: Yea, i understand this. But `unzip` won't :)

Comment: Thank you. The function in the comments of `Zip Functions` can be a way to go :) I'll try it.

Comment: I have used it and it works perfectly. If you may edit your answer to point to these functions - I will use it.

Comment: @JakubKrol, great ! I edited my answer. Thank you. ; )